# How to add a margin in BoxDecoration for Tab?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was trying to implement a margin in a TabBar but I didn't find anything. So my idea was to do a margin to the `BoxDecoration` of `TabBar` in the `indicator` parameter.

**This is what I want:**

[image: this is what I want]

**This is what I have:**

[image: this is what I have]

**The code for my implementation:**

```
DefaultTabController(
                length: 2,
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: kPaddingTabBar,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kLightGrey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: TabBar(
                      tabs: <Tab>[
                        Tab(text: kArtwork),
                        Tab(text: kPastJobs)
                      ],
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                      labelColor: Colors.black,
                      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: kRobotoBold,
                      ),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: kRobotoBold,
                      ),
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you can change two things to get more control of the tab bar indicator.  First, according to the [indicatorSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/indicator.html) documentation, The size of the selected tab indicator is defined relative to the tab's overall bounds if indicatorSize is TabBarIndicatorSize.tab or relative to the bounds of the tab's widget if indicatorSize is TabBarIndicatorSize.label.

Therefore, first change is to make change TabBarIndicatorSize.tab to:

```
TabBarIndicatorSize.label
```

Also, the Tab Widgets that you are using are limited in the ability to apply padding/margins, etc.  Therefore, your tab list should look use containers, instead of the Tab widget.  It should look something like this inside of the TabBar() widget:

```
tabs: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      width: 100, 
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child:Text("kArtwork"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      width: 100, 
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(child: 
                             Text("kPastJobs"),
                            ),
                    ),
```

Finally, to get the top and bottom padding, you have to use the border of the widget to simulate padding. (BoxDecoration does not have a padding property.)

Therefore, you need to add a Border widget to your indicator and set the color of the border equal to the background color.  It should look something like this:

```
indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
```

Comment: I updated the answer to add the top and bottom padding as well, since I forgot to mention it in the original answer.

Comment: I had enough indicator customized, I didn't use TabBarIndicatorSize.label

Answer (score 1):

you can add space by wrapping your Tab Bar Widget to a Padding and giving it padding

```
       Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  width: 100, 
                  height: 40,
                  child: Center(
                    child:Text("kArtwork"),
                  ),
                ),
```